How can a withdraw be made on a frozen account on a platform?
HTTPS://www.xk8868.com.    Aka: Bcokcoins.com
There is funds in this account and I would like to withdraw, it is either frozen or fake. How can I make a try at withdrawal. Do I need to convert USD to BTC to enable a transfer of funds. I’m new to this.

It sounds like they are asking for an advance fee. If they actually had your money and wanted to give it to you, they could deduct the fee from it and give you the rest. That they ask you to send them money instead, clearly indicates that they do not have the money.

Thanks that’s what I suspected.
